# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Корпус и запорный орган выполнены из 2 взаимно перпендикулярных (,) герметично соединенных между собой труб разного сечения, поэтому литейное производство корпуса и запорного органа не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна. Рядом стоящие прилагательное и причастный оборот являются однородными.

Comment: Спасибо большое!